# Getting Exception when setting Frame.Builder() in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am implementing face detection example in eclipse but when set Frame.Bulder() ,its throwing exception .Following is the CameraSource class in which exception is thrown.

```
  public void run() {
        Frame outputFrame;
        ByteBuffer data;

        while (true) {
            synchronized (mLock) {
                if (mActive && (mPendingFrameData == null)) {
                    try {
                        // Wait for the next frame to be received from the camera, since we
                        // don't have it yet.
                        mLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Frame processing loop terminated.", e);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if (!mActive) {
                    // Exit the loop once this camera source is stopped or released.  We check
                    // this here, immediately after the wait() above, to handle the case where
                    // setActive(false) had been called, triggering the termination of this
                    // loop.
                    return;
                }

                outputFrame = new Frame.Builder()
                        .setImageData(mPendingFrameData, mPreviewSize.getWidth(),
                                mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.NV21)
                        .setId(mPendingFrameId)
                        .setTimestampMillis(mPendingTimeMillis)
                        .setRotation(mRotation)
                        .build();

                // Hold onto the frame data locally, so that we can use this for detection
                // below.  We need to clear mPendingFrameData to ensure that this buffer isn't
                // recycled back to the camera before we are done using that data.
                data = mPendingFrameData;
                mPendingFrameData = null;
            }

            // The code below needs to run outside of synchronization, because this will allow
            // the camera to add pending frame(s) while we are running detection on the current
            // frame.

            try {
                mDetector.receiveFrame(outputFrame);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception thrown from receiver.", t);
            } finally {
                mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data.array());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and following is the log error

> 01-27 10:08:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(14778): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-268
>   01-27 10:08:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(14778): Process: com.example.customcamera, PID: 14778
>   01-27 10:08:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(14778): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image byte buffer must be allocated as 'direct'. See ByteBuffer.allocateDirect().
>   01-27 10:08:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(14778):    at com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame$Builder.setImageData(Unknown Source)
>   01-27 10:08:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(14778):    at com.example.customcamera.camera.CameraSource$FrameProcessingRunnable.run(CameraSource.java:1304)
>   01-27 10:08:10.368: E/AndroidRuntime(14778):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 3):

> That demo requires compiling with Google Play Services 8.1. I'm
>   guessing that you compiled with Google Play Services 7.8.
>
> This was the result of a bug fix that occurred between the two
>   versions. The issue is that using direct byte buffers with the
>   CameraSource class will result in a pixel shift of the images sent to
>   the detector (e.g., the position reported for the barcode may be
>   shifted to the left several pixels). In 8.1 we added support for
>   indirect byte buffers to address this, but the 7.8 library doesn't
>   have that ability.
>
> Long story short: Compile with 8.1 if you can. If you can't, you'll
>   need to change to direct byte buffers as suggested above, and
>   positions reported back will be off by several pixels.

Source: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/33